# Hide row based on a value from another dataset

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I have a tablix that has one dataset, and I need to hide one row based on a value in another dataset.

Currently I have this expression under visibility:

```
=Iif(Fields!Data1.Value="0" or Fields!Data2.Value="1", TRUE, FALSE)
```

Both of these are in another dataset called `vDataset3`.

Comment: I have a few questions, is there more than one row in this tablix making the first step to find this row? Also, is there more than one row in the second dataset that requires a lookup to match to this dataset?

Comment: There is only this row in the tablix. And there are more rows in the second dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code

```
=IIF(First(Fields!UserID.Value, "DataSet2") = 0 or
 First(Fields!UserID.Value, "DataSet2") = 12, True, False)
```

In order to call a field in another dataset you need to write:

```
First(Fields!UserID.Value, "DataSet2")
```

The first means that you take the first row. you have to do that because a dataset is like an array you must declare the field you would like to get.

and the `"DataSet2"` is the name of the dataset

Comment: Thank you.
Only thing i had to change is to put the values in quotations mark 0 = "0".